# How to repeat a command for every line in a textfile with given arguments from the textfile (Bash?)

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, grep, youtube-dl

I have a .txt file structured like this:

```
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:00:26,190 --> 00:00:26,670
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:00:59,490 --> 00:00:59,880
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:03:15,570 --> 00:03:16,230
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:03:44,160 --> 00:03:44,730
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:04:32,040 --> 00:04:32,370
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:04:49,860 --> 00:04:50,250
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:05:58,200 --> 00:05:58,620
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:08:59,280 --> 00:08:59,760
02.01.2021-EwkqKbhcH5Q.webm.srt-00:10:20,830 --> 00:10:21,340
02.02.2021-9RaIIX8ycHg.webm.srt-00:00:23,820 --> 00:00:24,210
02.02.2021-9RaIIX8ycHg.webm.srt-00:00:40,140 --> 00:00:40,590
02.02.2021-9RaIIX8ycHg.webm.srt-00:13:03,905 --> 00:13:04,295
02.03.2021-FcNGyLY4nuw.webm.srt-00:00:25,680 --> 00:00:26,190
02.03.2021-FcNGyLY4nuw.webm.srt-00:00:44,220 --> 00:00:44,700
```

I want to repeat for every line this command:

```
sh download_youtube.sh <youtube's URL> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs from time> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs to time> <output_file_name>
```

How do i map the url part and the timestamp part of the .txt lines to the command?

I am trying to make a tool https://github.com/moeC137/video-recutter/blob/main/readme.md that downloads all specific instances of a word beeing used on a youtube channel and compiles all instances into a compilation.

Comment: Would you please describe the example of the desired command line using just one line of the file? In addition, we'd encourage you to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: example for line 1: sh download_youtube.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwkqKbhcH5Q 00:00:26,190 00:00:26,670  clip1.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input file is formatted as a fixed width text, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1                                       # input filename
count=1                                         # filename serial number
while IFS= read -r line; do                     # read the input file assigning line
    vid=${line:11:11}                           # video id of youtube
    start=${line:32:12}                         # start time
    stop=${line:49:12}                          # stop time
    file=$(printf "clip%03d.mp4" "$count")      # output filename
    (( count++ ))                               # increment the number
    echo sh download_youtube.sh "youtube.com/watch?v=$vid" "$start" "$stop" "$file"
done < "$infile"
```

Save the code above as a file, say `mycmd.sh`, then execute it with `bash mycmd.sh file.txt` as a dry run. Note the `file.txt` is the file which contains the download information as posted. If the printed output looks good, drop `echo` of the `mycmd.sh` and execute the actual run.

Comment: Thx so much, this allmost worked just had to change it a bit:                                                            #!/bin/bash

infile=$1                                       
count=1    
while IFS= read -r line; do  
    vid=${line:11:11}    
    start=${line:32:12}         
    stop=${line:49:12}          
    file=$(printf "clip%03d.mp4" "$count")   
    (( count++ ))                               
     echo  < /dev/null sh download_youtube.sh "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$vid" "$start" "$stop" "$file"
done < "$infile"

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It'll be okay if you have found the  fix to meet your working environment and is now working. Cheers.