# Download only part of a youtube video precise by the millisecond

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, timestamp, youtube-dl

I used this bash script here to download only short parts of long yt videos:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388148/48971
    
    if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
            echo "Usage: $0 <youtube's URL> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs from time> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs to time> <output_file_name>"
            echo "e.g.:"
            echo "$0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1n5gXIPyws 00:00:25 00:00:42 intro.mp4"
            exit 1
    fi
    
    echo "processing..."
    
    from=$(date "+%s" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $2")
    to=$(date "+%s" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $3")
    
    from_pre=$(($from - 30))
    
    if [ $from_pre -lt 0 ]
    then
            from_pre=0
    fi
    
    from_pre_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$from_pre)
    from_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$(($from - $from_pre)))$(grep -o "\..*" <<< $2)
    to_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$(($to - $from_pre)))$(grep -o "\..*" <<< $3)
    
    command="ffmpeg "
    
    for uri in $(youtube-dl -g $1)
    do
            command+="-ss $from_pre_command_print -i $uri "
    done
    
    command+="-ss $from_command_print -to $to_command_print $4"
    echo "downloading with the following command:"
    echo "$command" 
    $command
```

but the problem is its only precise to the full second.
I want to use it to download a bunch of very short clips (only one word long mostly) those are often below 1 second long.

I tryed to fix this by using milliseconds in the date.
But then i found out bash can only subtract with integers.
Here is what i tryed:

```
from=$(date "+%s.%3N" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $2")
to=$(date "+%s.%3N" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $3")

function diff {
    diff="$(echo $from - 5 | bc)"
    echo $diff
}
from_pre=$diff
echo $diff
```

but the workaround using bc didnt work because later in the script its again throwing errors because bash dosnt know what to do with non integers.

a sample command would look like this:

```
sh download_youtube.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH3auOKyxio 00:06:28.230 00:06:28.740 clip004.mp4
```

and this works...if the the timeframe is more than 1 second.
Sadly i am out of knowlage here how to make it more precise.
This all is part of a project to make automated compilations of specific word from a youtube channel more on that here:
https://github.com/moeC137/video-recutter
I am very thankfull for every help

edit:

after a bit try an error i found out that this seams to work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388148/48971

if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <youtube's URL> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs from time> <HH:mm:ss.milisecs to time> <output_file_name>"
        echo "e.g.:"
        echo "$0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1n5gXIPyws 00:00:25 00:00:42 intro.mp4"
        exit 1
fi

echo "processing..."

from=$(date "+%s" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $2")
to=$(date "+%s" -d "UTC 01/01/1970 $3")



from_pre=$(($from - 20))
#to_post=$(($to + 20))

if [ $from_pre -lt 0 ]
then
        from_pre=0
fi

from_pre_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$from_pre)

from_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$(($from - $from_pre)))$(grep -o "\..*" <<< $2)

to_command_print=$(date -u "+%T" -d @$(($to - $from_pre)))$(grep -o "\..*" <<< $3)

#to_post_command_print=$(date -u "+%T.%3N" -d @$to_post)

command="ffmpeg "

for uri in $(youtube-dl -g $1)
do
        command+="-ss $from_pre_command_print -i $uri "
done

command+="-ss $from_command_print -to $to_command_print $4"
echo "downloading with the following command:"
echo "$command" 
$command
```

But i starting to think the orginal script actually works with milleseconds.

Because this:

```
sh download_youtube.sh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH3auOKyxio 00:06:28.230 00:06:28.740 clip004.mp4
```

works, but when try to combine it with the script from here [How to repeat a command for every line in a textfile with given arguments from the textfile (Bash?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982768/how-to-repeat-a-command-for-every-line-in-a-textfile-with-given-arguments-from-t) it dosent use the milliseconds anymore.

Solved

The orginal Script worked. It just didnt like the "," in the timestamps, i replaced them with "." and now its working.

Comment: The video data in YouTube are encoded with h.264, VP9, or other compression technology.
These compression packs multiple frames into so-called `GOP` to improve the
compression efficiency by using the temporal redundancy of video frames.
The typical length of GOP is one second or so depending on the format.
You cannot divide the video stream within the GOP unless you once download the stream
and decode it.

Comment: so if i want to have a snipped from 00:01:30:500 to 00:01:30:750 i would have to download the stream beginning a few seconds before start and stop a few sec after. Then i have to decode and cut that snipped again to the final lengh?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: in the original script it starts the download 30sec before the timestamp with this line  from_pre=$(($from - 30)) ill guess ill try to add something like this for the ending to_post=$(($to + 30))

Comment: Please take care of the addition/subtraction of time. You may need to carry to/borrow from minutes and/or hours. If you have a problem, edit the question or create a new thread. Good luck.

Comment: yes i posted my new findings as edit

Comment: Good job. Is your problem solved? Or do you still need to append the milliseconds portion to the download command?

Comment: Actually i think i can narrow it down now.
the script only works with milliseconds when they are after a dot not a ",", i edit as solved when i am sure thats it

Comment: I suppose the commented-out `date -u "+%T.%3N"` will work even if the millisecond digits are `000`.

Answer (score 2):

solved by replacing "," in timestamps with "."